# Why am I seeing "N"s when I run my code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm new at this and have been practicing on codewars- one of the challenges is a caesar cypher challenge and I've got it pretty much solved except for this one issue...
Here's the code I wrote:

```
def rot13(string)
  alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  arr = []
  string.each_char.with_index do |char, i|
    n = alpha.index(char.downcase)
    a = (n.to_i + 13) % 26
    unless alpha.include?(char.downcase)
      arr << char
    end
    if char == char.upcase
      arr << alpha[a].upcase
    else
      arr << alpha[a]
    end
    
  end
  return arr.join
end

puts rot13('10+2 is twelve')
```

and when I run my code it comes back as this-

1N0N+N2N Nvf Ngjryir

Why are the Ns showing up? Anyone know?

Comment: The `if`/`else` code after the `unless` block always executes, appending a capital N (`alpha[13].upcase`, because `char == char.upcase` always evaluates to true for non-lettters) to `arr`. You need extra control statements to prevent the code after the `unless` block from executing when it does.

Comment: Oh, yeah! That makes total sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, you never use `i`

Comment: You might be interested in String#[tr](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-tr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're not checking for non-alphabetical characters properly. Going through the logic:

- At line 5, you set `n` to the index of the character in your alphabet string `alpha`. Because only letters are included, this call to `#include?` returns `nil` for all characters that aren't letters (e.g. your string's first character, '1').
- At line 6, you set `a` to `n.to_i + 13`. Because `nil.to_i` is zero, this will always be 13 for any character that isn't a letter.
- In the block in lines 7-9, you push `char` to your array because it doesn't exist in `alpha` (and so you get '1' as the first character of your output).
- But then, in line 10, you push `alpha[a].upcase` as well if `char == char.upcase`. If `char` isn't a letter (e.g. initially '1'), it passes this test (because `'1' == '1'.upcase`) and your code pushes `alpha[13].upcase` to the output as well, and 'N' is the 13th letter of the alphabet.

Basically, your checks aren't sufficient. You need to account for numbers and other non-alphabetical characters properly each time.